# Javascript Form Validation check

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am doing some homework about form validation and have write some code but it is not valid with some problems. Can someone tell me what's wrong in them and fix them? Thanks

```
function formCheck() {
    var form = document.forms["contact_form"];
    if(form["first_name"]["last_name"].value == "") {
        alert("Please fill in the required name.");
        form["first_name"]["last_name"].focus();
        return false;
    }

    var zip = /^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$/.test;
    if(zip.test(form["zip_code"]).value == false){
        alert("Please fill in a valid zipcode.");
        form["zip_code"].focus();
        return false;
    }

    var phone = /^\[0-9]{10}$|^\([0-9]{3}\)[ ]?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/
    if(phone.test(form["phone_number"]).value == false){
        alert("Phone number input format is not valid.");
        form["phone_number"].focus();
        return false;
    }

    var email = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.])+@[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9])+\.([a-z])+$/
    if(email.test(form["email_address"].value == false){
        alert("Email format is not valid.");
        return false;
    }
    form.submit();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: here is the link:  http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~mintingt/jsvalidation.html, the function formcheck does not work with my 2 other functions (show current time and change background color). Is there any conflict?

Answer (score 0):

This seems incorrect:

```
if(form["first_name"]["last_name"].value == "") {
    alert("Please fill in the required name.");
    form["first_name"]["last_name"].focus();
    return false;
}
```

You may want to replace that with:

```
if(form["first_name"].value == "") {
    alert("Please fill in the required first name.");
    form["first_name"].focus();
    return false;
}
if(form["last_name"].value == "") {
    alert("Please fill in the required last name.");
    form["last_name"].focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! Here is the link:  http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~mintingt/jsvalidation.html, the function formcheck does not work with my 2 other functions (show current time and change background color). Is there any conflict?